# How to call getServerSideProps() in nested pages in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I have 2 pages (parent and child) with dynamic routes, and I want to call getServerSideProps() in the child only.
The first page, `[Post].js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import axios from 'axios'
import Index from './index'

const Post = ({ children, making }) => {
    return (
        <Index>
            {making
                ? (
                    <div>
                        <p>Making ID is: {making.id}</p>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                )
                : (<p>Item not found</p>)}
        </Index>
    )
}

Post.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    making: PropTypes.object,
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query: { makingID } }) => {
    const url = `http://localhost:1337/makings/${makingID}`
    const res = await axios.get(url)
    const making = res.data

    return { props: { making } }
}

export default Post
```

The second page (the parent), `[tabs].js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import Post from '../[Post]'

const tabs = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { tabs } = router.query

    return (
        <Post>
          hello {tabs}
        </Post>
    )
}

export default tabs
```

But if I use `Post` as a component, then `getServerSideProps()` does not work. I could use the function in tabs, but I want it in the child only.

Comment: How are you wanting the hierarchy to be? I usually set mine up like this: `[parent]/[child]` where `[parent]` is a folder, and `[child]` is a file *inside* the folder, and then I have a `[parent]` file on the same level as the `[parent]` folder for just navigating to the parent. It works out really well that way. Is that what you're after? So a person can go to `site/[parent]` and `site/[parent]/[child]` both?

Comment: You cant use getServerSideProps inside the child component, it'll only work on the page level. check this https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: @JoelHager yes, similar. Mine is `site/[child]/[parent]`, i know it's a bit confusing, but using the page names from my question it would be like `site/[Post]/[tabs]`. So I only want `Post` to hold the data. Actually `[tabs]` is only there so i can have the route `site/[Post]/[tabs]`

Comment: To be fair, in the context of the folder structure of Next, `[Post]` would be the parent folder, and `[tabs]` would be `[tabs].js` *inside* the `[Post]` folder, making it `pages/[Post]/[tabs].js` Does that make sense?

Comment: just use useEffect() instead of getServerSide inside child component

Comment: @JoelHager yes that makes sense, you're right. But I'm using `[Post]` component inside `[tabs.js]` because I want everything I've put into `[Post]` and all the data to also show up in `[tabs]`. In this case, `[Post]` sorta becomes like a child component inside `[tabs].js` if that makes sense.

Comment: Are you sure you can even have that kind of routing without an actual page? I've never seen it done that way. The way I described seems to be the best interpretation of what you're after, as you can pass the props of `[tabs]` and `[post]` into the page. I *really* feel like the best situation for you is to make `[tabs]` a folder with `[post]` inside of it, and then a sibling page called `[tabs].js`

Comment: @JoelHager that would work, and I agree with you that that's probably the best/only solution, but I want the url route to be `site/[post]/[tabs]` instead of `site/[tabs]/[post]` . Basically `[post]` and `[tabs]` has one-to-many relationship, each `[post]` can have many `[tabs]` and `[tabs]` will change based on the data that is fetched in `[post]`, that's why I want data fetching to happen in `[post]`. However, when the url is `site/[post]/[tabs]`, I want `[post]` to still show up in the page. I hope that makes sense. I was just wondering if there's a way to do exactly that

Comment: Both of those parameters would be present in the structure I mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

`getServerSideProps` function can be used only in a page. You can't use it in components. Instead, you can pass fetched data as props to page components.

Also, pages can't be nested. If pages share same components, then you can include these components in both pages.